# Firestore throwing permission error even when the document is added

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, firebase-security

I am adding a document to a collection and I see that the document is added however in the browser console I see that the error is being thrown for permission. If the document is successfully added I don't know why it is still throwing that error, below is the code

```
    const roomMesageRef = this.afs.firestore.collection('project_chat').doc(roomId).collection('messages');
    console.log('Message: ', message);
    roomMesageRef.add(message).then(success => {
      console.log('Successfully added: ', success);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('Exception: ', error.message);
    });
```

Here is the output in the browser console

[image]

Here are my security rules

```
match /project_chat/{projectChatId} {
    allow read: if isSignedIn();
  allow create: if isSignedIn() && isOwner(incomingData().createdBy);

  match /messages/{messagesId} {
    allow read: if isSignedIn();
    allow create: if isSignedIn() && isOwner(incomingData().userId);
  }
}

function isOwner(userId) {
    return request.auth.uid == userId;
}

function isOwnerByEmail(email) {
    return request.auth.token.email == email;
}

function isSignedIn() {
    return request.auth != null;
}

function existingData() {
    return resource.data;
}

function incomingData() {
    return request.resource.data;
}
```

When I use the simulator with the same data, it passes without any errors

Comment: There is missing information here.  What exactly are `isSignedIn`, `isOwner`, and `incomingData`?  We need to be able to see the entire set of rules.

Comment: @DougStevenson updated it

Comment: What exactly does `message` contain?  Does it meet the requirements of the rule?

Comment: The message contains the userID which is the fire base UID I am checking to allow creation of the document. My issue is that the document is being added as expected but I don’t understand why it is still throwing a permission error but still adding the document

Comment: That doesn't sound possible.  A single `set()` can't both complete successfully *and* generate an error.  Is there more code running that you're not showing?